# mobile and tablet website

Tags: css, mobile, web

I'm in the process of creating my website. the url is: http://bvanlieshout.com

It's far from done but I want to finish the home page first before I even start looking at the other pages.

So what I've tried is making everything with %. Using:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .frontImage{
    display:none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .frontImage{
    display:none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
        width: 100px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
  .nowWhat{
    width:800px;
  }
}
```

that works , sorta, when i check my mobile phone and open the page it doesn't hide the images. I'm guessing because the page width is still beyond 320/768 px. So basicly what im asking is some pointers, tips. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You're missing `px` from `max-width: 768`

Comment: You should validate your CSS and HTML: http://validator.w3.org/ http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: sorry i copied it wrong

Comment: look, im not asking for validation. I'm asking for some help, tips, pointers on how to make my site responsive. I could post the whole bunch of css here but that wouldnt make any sense.I've searched and searched but i couldn't find a clear answer. Mind giving some? I also did just now validate my CSS, and it holds no errors. I didn't copy it from my source file i was struggling using the code taggs here on stackoverflow @WesleyMurch  EDIT: the css does hold errors but it's of a font that I'm using, not my code has nothing to do with being responsive o.a

Comment: Don't get upset with me, I'm just trying to help. So many issues are caused by simple errors or typos, it's best to check first before debugging. However, yes - if you can please post a working, minimal example that displays your problem that would help a lot. Relying on an external website for the question to make sense isn't helpful (once you update it, the question is useless).

Comment: It's been bothering me for a day now. And i'm getting frustrated on how to fix this. if you check the website you'll see the .content has no min or regular width just max width set at 960px. Further i've tried it all but again, it holds no effect.. Also the external website, is the actual website im building. The problem i'm describing, is the actual problem. How am i going to update my question if the problem im trying to solve is the question how will i post a working example. ( confusing sentence i know) @WesleyMurch

Comment: My best advice with responsive design is to start building from mobile first. So your main CSS is all about the mobile, use your media queries to bring in content and not exclude it. Would you like some assistance I can help you out as I have been there and no exactly how frustrating this can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` inside of your `<head></head>`

Comment: bonus kudos to you sir, i am in debt to you!

Comment: My pleasure. Let us know if you need anymore assistance.